# Parsing Tableau xml does not preserve original file

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I try to work programmatically on Tableau desktop file (which are just xml file in spite of their .twb extension). I have many problem with lxml which doesn't preserve original content. To facilitate the explanation, imagine you have a test.xml file which contain the following text:

```
  <column caption='Choix Découpage'   name='[Aujourd&apos;Hui Parameter (copy 2)]'>
    <member name='Nb d&apos;annulations'  default-format='n#,##0.00&quot; annulations&quot;;-#,##0.00&quot; annulations&quot;' />
        <run>&#10;:</run>
    <calculation  formula='iif([FAC_TYPE] = &apos;Avoir&apos; , [Calculation_1378101492427309057], null)' />
    <alias key='&quot;Billetterie Ferroviaire&quot;' value='Train ticketing' />
  </column>
```

Now let's parse it:

```
tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(etree.tostring(root,pretty_print=True,).decode("utf-8"))
```

When you run the code we can notice:

- `'` becomes `"`
- `é` becomes `&#233;`  Edit: resolved for this part
- `&apos;` becomes `'`

How could i preserve the original ? (It would help me a lot when i try to check the diff with git in spite of showing all the useless change that are operated automatically)

**Edit**: I notice an other problem, when i run the folowing code:

```
[node.attrib['key'] for node in root.xpath("//alias")]
```

I got the result: `['"Billetterie Ferroviaire"']` and I am now unable to query with xpath if i am looking for the node whose attribute "key" is the original  `&quot;Billetterie Ferroviaire&quot;` (`root.xpath('//[@key="Billetterie Ferroviaire"])` doesn't work)

Comment: Just edited, the site interpret directly the characters

Comment: As far as XML is concerned, `é` and `&#233;` are *precisely* the same thing. Your XML has not changed.